# Facebook Ads Insights filtering by ad_name contain brackets "[[" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I try to get ads insight and filtering by ad_name. My ad name will be like **Test ad [[123]]**. if I filter by brackets **"[["** it will return null, I try escape it like **\[\[**, still error.

Here my code, if I change filtering value to normal letter (eg. Test ad) it will work filtering by ad_name contain the value I entered.

```
$params = array(
        'fields' => "ad_name,spend",
        'level' => "ad",
        'date_preset' => "today",
        'filtering' => "[{'field':'ad.name', 'operator':'CONTAIN', 'value':'[['}]"
    );
$request = new FacebookRequest($fb_session, 'GET', '/' . $ad_account . '/insights', $params, 'v2.8');
```

I think it kind of json format error but not sure how to fix it. More info [Ads Insights - Parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters#parameters)

Comment: Don’t assemble JSON manually; create the proper data structure instead, and then let json_encode handle this.

Comment: @CBroe I already try  json_encode same error. One thing I notice if I add letter to value it will work `'value':'[['` to `'value':'[[123]]'` or just one letter  `'value':'[[1'` it will get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

I just verified that the filtering API call works across for this. Chances are this was an issue that has already been fixed. Please ping this thread if this is still reproducing for you.

Comment: This should be a comment.